# Filling In GroupBox

Tags: wpf

I have a groupbox that contains nested stack panels that aren't filling in the groupbox entirely.  I would like to have all the stackpanels evenly spaced out filling in the entire groupbox.  I have attempted changing the VerticalContentAlignment to Stretch for the groupbox, but that does not work.

```
<GroupBox>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Test1" />
                <Label Content="Test2"/>        
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Test3" />
                <Label Content="Test4"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
</GroupBox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanels by default only use as much space as is required to display whatever they contain.  If you need different behavior you either need to roll your own version of a stackpanel or use another container.  Both Grids/Dockpanels work fine as substitutes.